# When I used layoutSubviews method of UItableViewcell with category in my file,something disappeared

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, layoutsubviews

when I used layoutSubviews method  of UItableViewcell with  category, just  like the code below

```
@implementation UITableViewCell (forimage)

- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
}

@end
```

when I used the code below to draw the cells , the **textLabel** was disappeared ,anyone know why it be that~, and does that mean if I use layoutSubviews,I must write all the subviews what I need in the method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    RadioInfo *radioinfo = [radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",radioinfo._name];

    if(!radioinfo._logo){
        if(self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO){
            [self startPicDownload:radioinfo forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    }
    else {
        cell.imageView.image = radioinfo._logo;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is add to the behaviour of UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews method, not replace it.

To properly add to the behaviour, subclass the cell and perform your own layout, as you have above but add a [super layoutSubviews] right at the top of your method to ensure that the cell's own basic layout is performed first.

Comment: ths,  got it,when I use [super layoutSubviews],actually "super" is not a cell~